# Java - jList getSelectedValue problem

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to convert an object (selected item on jList1) to a string but it is returning `null`.

I have tried:

```
Object object1 = jList1.getSelectedValue();
String string1 = object.toString();
```

&

```
String string1 = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

But they are both returning null for me, is there something I am doing wrong?

This is what happens when button1 is pressed:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Object object1 = jList1.getSelectedValue();
    String string1 = object1.toString();
    System.out.println(string1) 
}
```

Comment: Try `String string1 = jList1.getSelectedValue()`.

Comment: @Evan, that gives a Type Mismatch error (Cannot convert an object to string)

Comment: Okay, just making sure. The documentation examples for `JList` are unclear about how the return value is handled.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr, added the code for when jButton1 is pressed.

Comment: Doesn't help, that is NOT a SSCCE. Read the link!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Sorted this myself, not sure what was wrong but I copied the GUI and most of the code (apart from that section causing problems) to a new project re-wrote that part and it worked.

Comment: This answer doesn't help others who might come across the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

What type is this object? Have a look at the class's `toString` method if you can - chances are it is returning (incorrectly) `null`.

If `getSelectedValue()` returns a valid object, this is the only way for you to get `null`. If however it returned `null`, you should get a `NullPointerException` upon trying to call `toString` on the `null` reference. So I see no other possibility (provided the code snippet you posted is exact and your description is correct).

Comment: I believe it is the `getSelectedValue()` that is returning null and the snippets I posted above are what I am trying to use aswell as the description.

Comment: @Jamie, why don't you add a debug printout to test your theory? E.g. `if (object1 == null) System.out.println("selected value is null");`

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the toString() method on the selectedValue is returning null.

Has it been implemented properly?

Comment: I believe it is, although I do have something selected on the jList.

Comment: `int index = jList1.getSelectedIndex();`  use this to see if actually any of the value from the list is selected or not. If it is returning -1, then no value is selected.

Comment: @Rakesh, That returns `0`, `1`, `2`, etc depending on which item was selected.