# Null pointer Exception in JList when is ListSelectionListener is running

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlist

**I wrote some code that sets the Image on the JLabel. The path of Image is obtained from getSelectedValue() method for selected item on the JList.**

The Jlist was populated when user clicked search button by typing the item to be searched in JTextField(i.e searchTextField) after choosing any option out of three items in JComboBox(i.e typeChooserBox). Then my program reads saved records from a file "Records.txt" and breaks into tokens to compare proper token(based on index of typeChooserBox) with the user input value(in searchTextField). Then it populates JList.

Below is the event handler for search Button that populates JList.

```
    public class searchButtonListener implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
       model.clear();//This empties the JList creating nullpoint Ex
        int index=typeChooserBox.getSelectedIndex();
        String toCompare=searchTextField.getText();

        try {
                        File file = new File("Records.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line=null;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    String[] tokens = line.split("/");


                    if( index==0){
                        if(tokens[0].equals(toCompare))
                            model.addElement(tokens[2]);}

                    if(index==1){
                        if(tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase(toCompare))
                            model.addElement(tokens[2]);}
                    if(index==2){
                        if(tokens[3].contains(toCompare))
                            model.addElement(tokens[2]);}
                                    }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e2){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File not found", "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
        catch(IOException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File not found", "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

}
```

}

When I search for a record. For the First time -my JList gets populated with results of search .Then when I select an item from JList, it works(sets the correct image on JLabel) until I perform a new search. As soon as I click the search button(second time). My program throws nullPointExecption and stops working. Sorry I have not included SSCCE. But if these little information is not sufficient please let me know. :)

WELL I FIGURE OUT MY PROBLEM...
the code model.clear() clears all the item in the list when a search button is clicked. Due to this reason, there will be no selected item at the list resulting null pointer exception. But How do I solve this. Can I clear all the field but avoid null value when getSelctedValue() is called for the JList.

I tried doing this but it still didn't work.

```
    public class searchListListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        String s;
        String imagePath;


        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt){ try{

         imagePath= (String) searchResult.getSelectedValue();

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imagePath);
        imageLabel.setIcon(image);
        searchResult.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);




    }
        catch(NullPointerException ne){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NullPointerException");   
             model.addElement(s);
             searchResult.setSelectedValue(s, true);

            }
        finally{
            s=imagePath;
        }
}
    }




public class typeChooserBoxListener implements ItemListener{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev){

    }
}
```

I am new on this java world, Sorry if I have not been able to help you to help me.:(

Comment: provide us an `ne.printStackTrace()` output please

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310294/java-jlist-getselectedvalue-problem?

Comment: Do you always choose the same "first" and "second" item? If so, try changing what you pick "first" and "second".

Comment: @MarekSebera How do I use this stackTrace Method. Can you give me an info becoz I have never used it in my life. So I am unaware about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without the stack trace of your exception or what happens in searchResult.getSelectedValue().

Perhaps try this:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt){
    if( evt.getValueIsAdjusting() ) return;

    // your code here

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply... it didn't work. The same error occured again. a

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this way but it actually didn't work. It showed same error.Could you tell me how to print stacktrace of this error so that I can provide it to you all. I have never used this stacktrace before so I am unaware about it.

Comment: stacktrace is what ne.printStackTrace() prints out - and what you added 1 sec after I posted my answer ; )

Comment: ...you did make sure that the path to the image is valid and that the image is in a supported format (gif, jpg, png)?

Comment: Thank you I didn't knew that it was output of Stack Trace :D... ya and I have path of all the images in .png or .jpg format...

Comment: I have edited my Question .. I hope it helps to make my problem clear.